# Iterating and replacing dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, mapping

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['High', 'Central', 'Low', 'LowCentral], 
               'outcome': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']})
```

What I want to do is map the **outcome** column according to the **category** column in the following way:

- If *category* == High, *outcome* = Yes
- If *category* == Central, *outcome* = Maybe
- If *category* == Low, *outcome* = No

I have tried

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[i, 'category'].str.contains('High'):
       df.loc[i, 'outcome'] = 'Yes'
    elif df.loc[i, 'category'].str.contains('Central'):
       df.loc[i, 'outcome'] = 'Maybe'
    elif df.loc[i, 'category'].str.contains('Low'):
       df.loc[i, 'outcome'] = 'No'
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I also tried to use the 'map' function:

```
df['category'] = df['outcome'].map({'High':'Yes', 'Central':'Maybe', 'Low':'No'})
```

But this resulted in the 4th row i.e. LowCentral to output NaN in the outcome column, which is not desired.
I want to keep the outcome values that will not be included in the mapping.

Any help woud be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *LowCentral* contains both *low* and *central*, so one will overwrite the other, even if your code is correctly syntaxed. Can you rethink the logic please?

Comment: The name of the column is not that important.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a little mixed up.  What you want is to *map* the `category` column.  You were close with your map solution

```
df['outcome'] = df['category'].map({'High':'Yes', 'Central':'Maybe', 'Low':'No'}).fillna(df['category'])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The thing is 'LowCentral' can hold more than one values so I do not want to map it.

Comment: I've updated, see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['High', 'Central', 'Low', 'LowCentral'],'outcome': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']})
df['outcome'] = df['category'].replace({'High':'Yes','Central':'Maybe','Low':'No'})
print(df)
```

output

```
     category     outcome
0        High         Yes
1     Central       Maybe
2         Low          No
3  LowCentral  LowCentral
```

Note that unknowns are left without change

Comment: But the LowCentral changes from No to LowCentral which is unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['High', 'Central', 'Low', 'LowCentral'], 
               'outcome': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']})
               
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if   'High'    in df.loc[i, 'category']:
       df.loc[i, 'outcome'] = 'Yes'
    elif 'Low'     in df.loc[i, 'category']:
       df.loc[i, 'outcome'] = 'No'
    elif 'Central' in df.loc[i, 'category']:
       df.loc[i, 'outcome'] = 'Maybe'   
print(df)
```

[**Output**]

```
     category outcome
0        High     Yes
1     Central   Maybe
2         Low      No
3  LowCentral      No
```